# How to get by insufficient memory impass - can't access site?

Tags: 7

Can someone help me by this impasse?
I have multiple instances of Drupal running (for now).  One is for testing and major changes.  It seems that I cannot get past the WSOD on my testing instance.  The php.log indicates insufficient memory when database.mysql.inc runs.  I've tried my php.ini max memory setting at 256M and even -1 (unlimited) and restarted apache with no better results.  I can't run drush, can't access the test site.  I'm STUCK!

Can anyone suggest a method to get by this issue to allow me to move forward?  BTW - the other instances work just fine with a 128M max.

Answer (score 3):

There is 3 method to increase your PHP memory limit.  They are all outline in http://drupal.org/node/207036

The best way to check your current situation is to create a file in the root directory call phpinfo.php, with these lines of code

```
<?php
  print phpinfo();
?>
```

Then check the settings by going to http://www.example.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

What changed just prior to your out-of-memory issues? If it's a bad module or theme, you can always deactivate it by directly altering database values, namely setting the relevant project's status to '0' in the `system` table.